# Oracle Query listing hours in memory

Tags: sql, oracle11g

it's been 3 days that I'm looking for a solution but no way in oracle sql, I want to have a query to give me the following result in the first time, without creation of a table in my database:

```
Time24
00:00:00
00:00:01
00:00:02
00:00:03
.
.
23:59:59
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where/how do you want to store it?  In a temp table, table variable, or just print to screen or something?

Comment: Thank you Brad, 
I want to print them in screen like in Aleksej and Gordon answers

Comment: @APC Yes it's a old server of the company :)

Comment: Oh my god, I just checked the version it's 11g et non 8, Sorry @APC !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `connect by` to generate the numbers you want and then format them as a string:

```
select to_char(to_date('00:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') + (level - 1) * interval '1' second, 'HH24:MI:SS') as time24
from dual
connect by level < 24*60*60;
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a way, by building intervals and then extracting hours, minutes and seconds from them:

```
select extract(hour from seconds) hours,
       extract(minute from seconds) minutes,
       extract(second from seconds) seconds
from  (      
        select level  * interval '1' second as seconds
        from dual
        connect by level <60*60*24
      )
```